# How to fix "ADS AND CONTENT OVERLAP"

Tags: android, admob

I have a live application and use admob banner in it. 
today i received an warning "ADS AND CONTENT OVERLAP"

This is my xml code where i place ads banner

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="info.white.kora.Main" >


<ProgressBar

    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="5dip"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:id="@+id/progressbar_Horizontal"
    android:max="100"
    android:background="#228b22"
    />

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true" />



<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|center|end"
    ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"></com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

How i could use admob banner with webview correctly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add below attributes to Webview.

```
        android:layout_above="@+id/adView"
```

Answer (score 2):

Just wanted to post what I had to do to remove the violation with my banner ad which is placed at the bottom of each view.

This places a banner ad at the bottom of the screen:

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    xmlns:googleads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:id="@+id/ad"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:visibility="gone"
    com.google.android.gms:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
    com.google.android.gms:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-xxxxx"
    googleads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-xxxxx" />
```

Ensure the parent view (Relative/Linear layout etc) above the banner has:

```
android:layout_above="@+id/adView"
```

You might also find you need to add a margin above the ad:

```
android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
```

or below your content:

```
android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
```

This link had more useful information then the "learn more" about this violation link in admob:

https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6275335?hl=en&ref_topic=2745287

The above steps will remove the "overlap" violation. I went through the layout of my entire app (about 50 layouts) and any with an ad I explicitly had to set this. Even though the app visibly might look fine to users (eg a banner ad is at the bottom of the screen correctly) I suspect a bot is checking from the admob side as I got no communication back when I emailed them and rejections were really quick (1 hour). It took more than 10 attempts to remove the violation.